# WPF Style with multiple contents

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have created a style that creates a Label as a circle with the text in the middle.

```
<Style x:Key="RoundedLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="cp" Margin="0,0,0,0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Width}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <ContentPresenter.Content>
                            <Border Padding="10">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>                                            
                            </Border>
                        </ContentPresenter.Content>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Its used in this way:

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource RoundedButtonStyle}" Content="{Binding CountValue}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Background="Red" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3" Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" />
```

This works fine.

However I want to add further information to this label by having two text fields in different locations.

1. The first one already exists and displays in the centre of the ellipse.
2. Id like to add one which displays underneath the Ellipse.

Id like to be able to implement it in pure xaml if it is possible and use it something like this where the binding to SecondLabelText shows under the Ellipse:

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource RoundedButtonStyle}" Content="{Binding CountValue}" SecondContent="{Binding SecondLabelText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Background="Red" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3" Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" />
```

I can add the label into the style, but how do i set two separate contents?

Comment: A Label element only has a single Content. If you need multiple contents, create a custom control. As a workaround for a "secondary content" people often use the Tag property.

Comment: @Clemens Tag is a great idea. Thanks.

Comment: Just create your own USerControl. Follow [this](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html) article to know the tricks. You can have as many properties to bind as you want

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this is any use to you; went away and created this as a custom user control as a bit of a practice, You can create a new user control, setting 2 properties to receive the 2 contents:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Custom_Control_Elipse_2_labels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for EllipseWithTwoLabels.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class EllipseWithTwoLabels : UserControl
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty Content1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Content1", typeof(string), typeof(EllipseWithTwoLabels));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Content2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Content2", typeof(string), typeof(EllipseWithTwoLabels));
        public EllipseWithTwoLabels()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public string Content1
        {
            get => (string) GetValue(Content1Property);
            set => SetValue(Content1Property,value);
        }
        public string Content2
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(Content2Property);
            set => SetValue(Content2Property, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The .xaml for the user control being

```
<Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Content1}" Style="{StaticResource RoundedButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Background="Red" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3" Height="100" Width="100" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" ></Label>
        <Label Content="{Binding Content2}" Margin="0,150,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></Label>
    </Grid>
```

You can then just import it into any view to use it with: (

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Custom_Control_Elipse_2_labels"
```

And use with the xaml:

```
 <local:EllipseWithTwoLabels Height="300" Width="300" Content1="Content #1" Content2="Content #2"/>
```

Is one way to get it done :)

It provides something like this:
[image]

Comment: As advice, I will tell you not to set `DataContext` at root. Also, do it in XAML, so you have IntelliSense. Read [this](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html) to know why

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example `Tag` property of label to store extra data

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource RoundedLabelStyle}" Content="Content" Tag="Content#2"/>
```

In template just bind to `Tag` property

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
```

Better approach is to use [`AttachedProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview). This allow you declare as many extra content as you want, without creating new type of control

```
public class LabelExtension 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondContentProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "SecondContent", typeof(object), typeof(LabelExtension));

    public static void SetSecondContent(UIElement element, object value)
    {
        element.SetValue(SecondContentProperty, value);
    }
    public static object GetSecondContent(UIElement element)
    {
        return (object)element.GetValue(SecondContentProperty);
    }
}
```

Set it on control

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource RoundedLabelStyle}" Content="Content" local:LabelExtension.SecondContent="Content#2"/>
```

Use from within template

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding local:LabelExtension.SecondContent}"/>
```

Complete label style example

```
<Style x:Key="RoundedLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                        <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                            <Ellipse x:Name="cp" Margin="0,0,0,0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Width}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                    <Border Padding="10">
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
                                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding local:LabelExtension.SecondContent}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </ContentPresenter.Content>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

[image: Proof image]